# How to dynamically add widget with a ontap

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a nested for loop for dynamically creating buttons like a widget. Everything is working smoothly in terms of the layout. However, when I tap the buttons, the tap function will execute with the wrong button id (used the current button id instead of the one I used to create it ) (the index I used to create the button)  Does anyone have an idea about how should I fix this problem? thanks.

```
class ButtonItemsModel {
final String image;
final Color color;
final String title;
final String description;
final String ontap;
ButtonItemsModel({
  @required this.color,
  @required this.description,
  @required this.image,
  @required this.title,
  @required this.ontap,
});
}
```

```
for (var row_count = 1; row_count <= _no_of_row; row_count++) {
      buttoncells = [];
      for (var button_cell_count = 1; button_cell_count <=
          _rowwidgetno; button_cell_count++) {
        if (buttonid >= buttonItems.length) {
          break;
        }
        buttoncells.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
              hpadding, vpadding, hpadding, vpadding),
          child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: button_width + 30,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          // button color
                          elevation: (10),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          ),
                          color: buttonItems[buttonid].color,
                          child: InkWell(
                            customBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            splashColor: Colors.red,
                            onTap: () async {
                               //here is the part that i have problems with
                              if (await canLaunch(
                                  buttonItems[buttonid].ontap)) {
                                await launch(buttonItems[buttonid].ontap);
                              } else {
                                throw 'Could not launch' +
                                    buttonItems[buttonid].ontap;
                              }
                            },
                            child:
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),

                              child: SizedBox(
                                  width: button_width, height: button_width,
                                  child: Image(image: AssetImage(
                                      buttonItems[buttonid].image),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ),
                        Text(buttonItems[buttonid].title),
                      ],
                    )
                )
              ]
          ),
        ),
        );
        buttonid = ((row_count - 1) * _rowwidgetno + button_cell_count);
      }
        buttonrow.add(Row(
        children: buttoncells,
      ));
    }
    main_column = Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: buttonrow,
    );
  }
```

Comment: The explanation about the problem with the IDs is a bit confuse. Can you explain better what is happening?

Comment: So on the on tap function, for example, when i tap the third button, what i intend to do is to have the button id in buttonItems[buttonid].ontap be three,if i were to tap the forth button, i intend it to be four, yet, not matter which button i press, the buttonid would always be 13, i think it is 13 as i have 12 buttons and when the buttonid reaches 13 it would exit the loop, so say if i were to have 14 buttton, then no matter which button i tap, buttonid would always be 15

Comment: Why you assign buttonid in this way `buttonid = ((row_count - 1) * _rowwidgetno + button_cell_count);` instead of just increment its value? You shoud get the buttonId according with the index of your `buttonItems` list.